# my iptables not work and don't block any ip

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

my `iptables` doesn't work and don't blocking ip

i try to block this ip `66.85.48.9` using this rules

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 66.85.48.9 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -d 66.85.48.9 -j DROP
```

but when i ping my ip server from that ip machine i got reply not timed out

and this my service status

```
root@vmi:~# service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ + ]  ddos
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ - ]  fail2ban
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ + ]  gdm
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  mysql
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ogp_agent
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ - ]  openbsd-inetd
 [ - ]  postfix
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  psad
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ + ]  pure-ftpd
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: It's possible that your blocked computer has more than one IP.  If you will run these commands and add the output to your question the answer can be more definitive.

From the blocking computer run these command: **(1)** `sudo iptables -L -n | egrep 66.85.48.9` **(2)** `hostname -I`. From the computer being blocked run these commands: **(3)** `hostname -I` **(4)** `ping -c5 ip-of-server-computer`.  Replace `ip-of-server-computer` with the actual IP of your server computer.  Append the output of each command to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your iptables rules are working and blocking all ports** for the machine `66.85.48.9`.

You can verify that the machine's IP is blocked by testing specific services and ports such as `ssh` for port `22`, `ftp` for port `21`, or `telnet 66.85.48.9 80` to test the default web page port.  In the **telnet** command replace the `66.85.48.9` with the the IP of your IP Server.

Your command doesn't block ping request.  **Use this rule to block the ping request** of your other machine:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 66.85.48.9 -p icmp -j DROP
```

**Note**:
Since from your output, you are running the **Apache2** service, you can verify that access to if for machine 66.85.48.9 is blocked by your current rule.

**Rules for Preventing udp flooding**

In this example you can block udp from all sources while providing access to the desired source, such as your DNS server... in this example, Google's DNS servers are permitted.  Use the same method to allow access from any other IP you wish to allow.

```
# allow dns requests to google nameservers
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT


# block all other udp
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
```

Comment: yes tha't work now but still udp port not blocking, he can making udp flood on my vps even if he blocked

Comment: Are you saying the machine can flood your port with the **icmp** drop rule in place?